# Scroll is not smoothly while having 3000rows and 300 cols in a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, latency

I have implemented a `DIV` based structure to handle a large table. As the page is getting loaded properly while I am scrolling to the page, there is significant lagging. It slows down the overall work efficiency.

I am unable to post the code here as it's size is more than allowed size in post. Please find link in comment.

Please suggest any changes required in script to work it smoother.

Requirement is such that I can not do lazy-loading or load a content segment wise as it output flicks while I am scrolling.

Is there any possible solution to make it work without a flicking issue?

Comment: Please find JS fiddle code : https://jsfiddle.net/sapans/muv1embe/22/

Comment: @AngelPolitis In real time i am loading it with PHP code.To load document is not an issue. Scrolling is the issue after the page load.

Comment: Still, the table is very big. You should either split it or reduce it. I saw a lot of duplicate columns in as little time as I had before jsfiddle crashed again.

Comment: @AngelPolitis : All the data are duplicating as of now. As i have made this a sample for you people.I can not make it as smaller table or can not divide it into the paging.

Comment: "*Please suggest any changes required*" - yes, change your requirement.  Export to csv/excel or use a reporting tool like SSRS.

Comment: @freedomn-m : Right now we are doing in excel.To replace excel we have built this system.So, we can't go back.

Comment: Let's confirm: You're loading nearly a *million* divs before any content, so that's 10Mb of *just empty html*, into a system designed to display, on average around 60k (html only).  *And you wonder why it's slow*?

Comment: @freedomn-m : In actual scenario HTML is of 500Kb, As i am rendering gzip output. So, 10MB compressed to 500kb.

Comment: I'm not sure the browser displays compressed html, I'd be interested to know how you are "rendering gzip output" without decompressing it into the browser (or the browser automatically decompressing it).  But you missed my point.

Comment: @freedomn-m We can compress output by mod_deflate module of apache server. I somewhat agreed on your point that number of DOM nodes are too much.

Comment: "apache server" - not heard of that browser....!  The problem isn't sending the data - it's rendering it... ie the browser decompresses your gzip in order to render it.  So the transfer size is irrelevant at that point.